# How to stop trailing zeros splitting across cell with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm building a web scraper. The top line on this data scrape splits the title because there the number "1,000" at the end. How do I stop this from happening?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.topcashback.co.uk/easyjet-holidays/'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("tr")[1:]
filename = "topcashbackEasyJetholidays.csv"
f = open(filename,"w")
headers = "title, rate \n"
f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    title = container.td.div.span.text
    rate = container.find("span",{"class":"cashback-desc"}).text
    print("title: " + title)
    print("rate: " + rate)
    f.write(title + "," + rate + "," "\n") 

f.close()
```

Comment: `pandas.read_html()` can be very useful in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

The easy and ugly way - cover title with quotes so the comma in 1,000 won't be treat as separator in csv.

```
f.write('"' + title + '",' + rate + "," "\n") # btw. why the last comma?
# or with f-string
f.write(f'"{title}",{rate}\n")
```

The more fancy way - use [csvwriter](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-write-csv-file/)

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I didn't even realise it was being treated as a separator, makes so much more sense now! The last comma is just laziness on my part. :S

Comment: Glad could help, finger crossed your code will work as expected now!

Answer (score -1):

Here's the "fancy way", which I think is clearly the better way to go.  I find it to actually be an easier and simpler way to code up the problem:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

my_url = 'https://www.topcashback.co.uk/easyjet-holidays/'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.findAll("tr")[1:]
filename = "topcashbackEasyJetholidays.csv"
with open(filename,"w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["title", "rate"])
    for container in containers:
        title = container.td.div.span.text
        rate = container.find("span",{"class":"cashback-desc"}).text
        print("title: " + title)
        print("rate: " + rate)
        writer.writerow([title, rate])
```

There are other advantages to using a CSV writer.  The code is more readable and the details of the CSV file format are hidden.  There are other characters that could cause you problems and the CSV writer will transparently deal with all of them.  The CSV writer will only use quotes when it has to, making your CSV file smaller.  If you support multiple output formats, the same code can be used to write all of them by just creating different kinds of writers at the start of the writing code.

Answer (score -1):

I would check out this before trying to reinvent the wheel:

```
import pandas as pd

my_url = 'https://www.topcashback.co.uk/easyjet-holidays/'
tables = pd.read_html(my_url, encoding='utf-8')
df = tables[0]
df.columns = ['title', 'n/a', 'rate']
df = df[['title', 'rate']]
df.to_csv("topcashbackEasyJetholidays.csv", index=False)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                   title    rate
0  London Gatwick Departures over £1,000  £50.00
1        Holiday Bookings £1000 and Over  £40.00
2        Holiday Bookings £999 and Under  £25.00
```

CSV:

```
title,rate
"London Gatwick Departures over £1,000",£50.00
Holiday Bookings £1000 and Over,£40.00
Holiday Bookings £999 and Under,£25.00
```

You'll also need to have lxml installed, aka `pip install lxml`

Comment: I see a number of disadvantages to this approach.  I find it less readable, particularly so if you aren't familiar with Pandas.  It requires to bring in a number of additional packages.  Most importantly, it is making a lot of assumptions about how and where the data is on the page.  What if the table I want to read is the third one on a page?  What if the data isn't in a HTML table?   If  this extraction is part of a larger scrape, won't  Pandas have to refetch the page an extra time for each table it extracts? - Also, since this doesn't use BS, it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Pandas can use BeautifulSoup for this method, and includes plenty of ways to modify what's being parsed with common bs4 tools. Without modifications it gives you a list of all tables on the page, iterating through these to find the expected table is not out of the question, nor is using the bs4 methods to specify the table. If you expected me to create a complete web scraping tool that can work for every case... not something the author has even come close to doing, you've set some ridiculous expectations.